# Array inside Password Protection Pages with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, authentication

how do I add in an array of usernames and passwords to login using a very simple php password protection page? Here is the code i've gotten so far from someone elses question, just didn't have my answer.

```
 <?php
$username = array( "test1" . "test2" . "test3" );
$password = array( "test1pass" . "test2pass" . "test3pass" );
$nonsense = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";
if (isset($_COOKIE['PrivatePageLogin'])) {
if ($_COOKIE['PrivatePageLogin'] == md5($password.$nonsense)) {
?>
<!-- LOGGED IN CONTENT HERE -->
<?php
 exit;
 } else {
   echo "Bad Cookie.";
  exit;
 }
}
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
 if ($_POST['user'] != $username) {
  echo "Sorry, username does not match. <br /> <a href='index.php'> <--Back. </a>";
     exit;
   } else if ($_POST['keypass'] != $password) {
      echo "Sorry, that password does not match. <br /> <a href='index.php'>        <--Go Back. </a>";
       exit;
   } else if ($_POST['user'] == $username && $_POST['keypass'] == $password)      {
   setcookie('PrivatePageLogin', md5($_POST['keypass'].$nonsense));
  header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
 } else {
  echo "Sorry, you could not be logged in at this time.";
  }
 }
?>
```

Except, the `$username` variable used to be `$username = "my-user";`
How do I fix this Array list of usernames and passwords?

Comment: arrays need to be seperated by commas, not dots. Dots "concatenate".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ah ok, let me try this

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even when I do this, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Use error reporting to see if any errors comes of it, as per my link up there.

Comment: I use phpcodechecker.com . Didn't come back any errors. However, when I put this into action (with the edit you said to do) it comes back with username doesn't match...

Comment: that code checker most likely won't output errors, I've seen that happen before. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code and run it on your own server and see. I also don't know what the html form contains neither, as I see a mix of GET/POST.

Comment: Would the error codes show up in the javascript console? Or on the main page @Fred-ii-

Comment: you've no JS here. Plus, how are you accessing, from your own machine? if so, is a webserver/PHP installed? if local, using `http://localhost/file.php` or as `c:///file.php`? That would show up on screen if there were PHP errors btw.

Comment: I use XAMPP for localhost connection @Fred-ii-